# Remove Characters after occurrence of "."

Tags: c#

If the string is "abcd.vv" the code has to remove the ".vv" and return only "abcd". I am using the bellow code but it gives me error like

**"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"**

```
public string remChar(string LicID)
{
    if (LicID.Contains("."))
      {
        int index = LicID.IndexOf(".");
        return LicID.Substring(0, index);
      }
    else LicID;
}
```

Comment: `else return LicID;` ;)

Comment: You can accomplish this a bit more simply with `return LicID.Split('.').First()`

Comment: @CarstenKönig lol, loving how currently only a comment is answering the question...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth IMO as a simple syntax error this deserves neither real answer nor rep ;) - ofc you will get the upvote from me anyway :D

Comment: lol - I am waiting for the answers writing a VS extension to add missing `return` statements ... - you got to love SO

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yeah I tend to do that, quick question is a quick comment answer and move along, someone else will come along, make the proper answer to close out the question (or the OP can themselves do it).

Comment: What is wrong with posting different answers to a question? Is this site not about learning? I find them interesting.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul no it's not about learning - it's want to be a collection of good answers and questions - I don't mind but if the "Watchers" will see this thread will be closed in no time ...oops and it already is ;)

Comment: I disagree with that entirely but each to their own. There is nothing wrong with answering & suggesting an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is failing is because you are missing a return statement.

```
public string remChar(string LicID)
{
    if (LicID.Contains("."))
      {
        int index = LicID.IndexOf(".");
        return LicID.Substring(0, index);
      }

    return LicID;
}
```

Something like this could also work and simplifies it a little bit...

```
using System.Linq;


public string removeChar(string LicID)
{
    return (LicID ?? "").Split('.').First();
}
```

Comment: Get a null check with `return (LicID ?? "").Split('.').First();` Also, this wasn't the question.

Comment: I get Error "System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @xyz `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I use this  C# code in Biztalk. And I am newbie to C#.

Comment: Added using System.Linq; to answer.

Comment: Downvoted for stealing Asad's answer. Bad practice. Good luck with your downvote

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, my only answer would be that you don't need this code because yours currently works, the answer is the comment from Carsten.

Comment: @kmarois Collaboration isn't discouraged on this site. If someone posts a comment and not an answer, and someone posts it as an answer because it is, then let them. Neither this answer nor yours actually answers the question.

Comment: Yes I missed return statement. But just wanted to try one line works for my requirement

Comment: @Adam - I was referring to Ben - he's being a tard in my answer, so turnabout is fair play

Comment: @kmarois I know who you were referring to, I am following this rubbish. None of it is the remit of this site and detracts from its value.

Comment: Added the null check and answered the OP's original question for completeness.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Regarding "this wasn't the question", there was no question. The OP pasted a bunch of code and described a compiler error they were getting. If anyone had to guess from the title, "how to remove characters after occurrence of '.'" would be a reasonable guess at what OP is asking for, which this answer provides.

Comment: @asad Consistency between the title and the content doesn't always happen. In that case I would err on the side of completeness and answer both. That still doesn't detract from the fact that the provided code, once compiling was doing what was required.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yes, that's all well and good, and explaining what is wrong in the question is important. That doesn't mean that an answer that provides an alternative approach, especially for a question as underspecified as this one, is "not answering the question".

Comment: @asad well I certainly didn't get the vibe that it needed rewriting. The code itself demonstrated the given issue when copied into a test app. But I still believe that answering a question that wasn't asked without attempting to also address the main problem (even with a sentence stating that the replacement code no longer has the problem) is not addressing the question. It adds value along with an explanation, not simply on its own.

Comment: Sorry guys but the answer does infact answer the question... it is quite standard for me to post a question and then continue editing it add value.

Comment: @benjaminpaul Yes it does now, after edits made after the comments. The rest of the comments are just a discussion about the original.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth "I still believe that answering a question that wasn't asked..." I'll reiterate: there was no question asked. The closest the OP came to asking a question was stating what they wanted in the title of their question. Lack of added value falls well short of "not an answer". I think I'll stop now, this question is not worth this much debate.

Comment: @asad No there wasn't a question, but it wasn't hard to infer it given the compiler error. I agree, no more value in this, its closed anyway lol

Answer (score 2):

To stop the profusion of confusing answers, your current code has a compiler error for the reason Carsten points out, nothing more. Other than that and a few defensive checks, it works.

This will compile and also do what you need it to (plus a little extra checking, ignoring case, and removing superfluous statements):

```
public static string RemoveCharactersAfterFirstPeriod(string value)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && value.Contains("."))
    {
        int index = value.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        return value.Substring(0, index);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Or with Linq:

```
public static string RemoveCharactersAfterFirstPeriod(string value)
{
    return (value ?? "").Split('.').First();
}
```

If it is unit tested and meets your requirements, changing it for a single line is a zero-value prospect. My only change would be to rename the method to C# naming standards.

Comment: guys - why would anyone downvote the only meaningful answer in all this mess?

Comment: What value did this bring above my answer?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul It points out that the only incorrect thing in the question is the compiler error, which your answer didn't initially mention (looking at the edit history). It also fixates on wanting to re-write something that works. I point out naming standards and the value of unit testing your requirements.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul none but if you have enough rep to look at your "edit stack" you will see that you changed your answer over time to reflect other answers and comments - but nice try

Comment: @CarstenKönig ... Yes... that is encouraged on SO in order to improve an answer and make it more comprehensive.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul It is, but there is little point in questioning the value of other answers that are also correct. You can either improve them directly through edits, improve them indirectly through additional answers, upvote them for value, downvote them for being incorrect, or ignore them. I would have chosen to upvote or ignore. I'm guessing my two downvotes are spiteful as opposed to relevant.

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted you, I will remove my answer leaving yours simply because I prefer your method name... "RemoveCharactersAfterFirstPeriod" cleary indicates intent better than the one I came up with.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Fair enough. I am quite happy with the single downvote, because it puts my rep onto a number ending in 5, which is more round than 7 so far as my OCD is concerned.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Regex`.

```
public static string ExtractString(string text)
{
    if (text == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

    return Regex.Match(text, @"^[^\.]*").Groups[0].Value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Regex.Match("input.foo", @"([^\.]*)\.?.*").Groups[1].ToString()
```

Returns input

```
Regex.Match(".foo", @"([^\.]*)\.?.*").Groups[1].ToString()
```

returns the empty string

```
Regex.Match("input", @"([^\.]*)\.?.*").Groups[1].ToString()
```

returns input

```
Regex.Match("", @"([^\.]*)\.?.*").Groups[1].ToString()
```

returns the empty string

```
Regex.Match("input.foo.bar", @"([^\.]*)\.?.*").Groups[1].ToString()
```

returns input

Answer (score -3):

Assuming your string is always in XXX.XXX format, why not just do this:

```
string result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(licID);
```

Comment: `Why not just do this` because it doesn't express intent. You could use that method, but put it in another method with a nice name such as `RemoveCharactersAfterFirstPeriod`. For the record, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Agree, does not express intent. Bad practice.

Comment: I meant replace his 6 lines of code with that 1 statement. Do I really need to write the whole function out in my answer?

Comment: The issue is with "Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(licID);" ... As it is not a file name you are working with this is a misleading statement.

Comment: @kmarois Yeah, I see nothing wrong with using it to do the job (nice trick), but I'd wrap that in something that doesn't talk about file names and extensions.

Comment: @Adam - I love when people throw out "Bad Practice", as if writing a function with 6 lines of code to do something the framework already does is "Good Practice".

Comment: This will throw an exception if the string contains any characters that are invalid for a path.  For that reason it should only be used if the string is actually a path or the OP can be sure it will never have any of the invalid path characters in it.

Comment: @Benjamin, Bad Practice is reinventing the wheel. Insulting me is poor taste.

Comment: @kmarois Yes the framework provides an implementation that can possibly substitute, but it does so in a black box under a different name for a conceptually different purpose. Also, it doesn't actually cope with multiple instances of `.`.

Comment: There is absolutely NOTHING wrong with my answer. It's Framework code that does the job, and I qualified my answer with "Assuming your string is always in XXX.XXX format, why not just do this"...
 "